# ubuntu second monitor black after doing the following steps

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, cuda

I was following the steps below to solve a problem and now my second monitor is black(it is detecting the monitor and everything but its only displaying a black screen) can anyone please help me fix it I have been at it for hours(writing this post at 2am).I have a rtx3050 ti on an Asus laptop. I am afraid that I might have deleted some important pakages.

**The Steps**

Even with those commands, the issue wasn’t solved.
Eventually, the fastest way to fix 2 machines with a package manager is to purge all Nvidia & Cuda,did it by:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'
```

Then after it’s clean ran that:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

**From here - it’s the same for all VMs:**

Download [latest run](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) 3.3k file from Nvidia site, and run it, accept if needed to upgrade current, or install from scratch.
The driver is back to work.

The issue was started after did some updates, and the Linux kernel was changed.